# How can I serve binary content from a JSF/Webflow app?

Tags: java, jsf, streaming, spring-webflow

I have a JSF 1.2/Spring Web flow 2.0.7 app that need to serve binary content (an image). This content is fetched from a web service (along with some other data) as a Base64-encoded string, and ends up in the bean together with the rest of the data. How can I get the image to show on my web page?

Note: No, there is no way to make the web service stream the data directly, or even to get the binary data out of the web service without all the other stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to end up with that image in a `<h:graphicImage>` component, right? In theory, you could use the [`data` URI format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) for this.

```
<h:graphicImage value="data:image/png;base64,#{bean.base64Image}" />
```

However, you've the problem that it doesn't work across all of the current browsers. MSIE for example limits the length of `data` URI to 32KB.

If those images are in general larger or you'd like to support outdated browsers as well, then your currently best bet is really to let it point to a fullworthy URL *after all*.

```
<h:graphicImage value="images/filename.png" />
```

There are two ways to get this to work:

1. Write the image temporarily to public webcontent and reference it the usual way.

   ```
   this.uniqueImageFileName = getOrGenerateItSomehow();
   byte[] imageContent = convertBase64ToByteArraySomehow();
   ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
   ServletContext sc = (ServletContext) ec.getContext();
   File image = new File(sc.getRealPath("/images"), uniqueImageFileName);
   // Write byte[] to FileOutputStream on that file the usual way (and close!)
   ```

   And use it as follows:

   ```
   <h:graphicImage value="images/#{bean.uniqueImageFileName}" />
   ```

   This however only works if the WAR is expanded and you have write rights to the disk file system. You also need to take cleanup into account. A `HttpSessionListener` may be helpful in this.
2. Store the binary data in session and have a `HttpServlet` to serve it up. Assuming that your bean is request scoped:

   ```
   this.uniqueImageFileName = getOrGenerateItSomehow();
   byte[] imageContent = convertBase64ToByteArraySomehow();
   ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
   ec.getSessionMap().put(uniqueImageFileName, imageContent);
   ```

   and the view look like this:

   ```
   <h:graphicImage value="images/#{bean.uniqueImageFileName}" />
   ```

   Create a `HttpServlet` which is mapped on an `url-pattern` of `/images/*` and does like the following in the `doGet()` method:

   ```
   String uniqueImageFileName = request.getPathInfo().substring(1);
   byte[] imageContent = (byte[]) request.getSession().getAttribute(uniqueImageFileName);
   response.setContentType("image/png"); // Assuming it's always PNG.
   response.setContentLength(imageContent.length);
   // Write byte[] to response.getOutputStream() the usual way.
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The last part is what I ended up doing, except that the bean containing the data was in WebFlows flowscope, not in any JSF scope. So I called some code in the flow that copied the bean from SWFs flow scope to the session. Then I retrieved the data from the session in the Servlet. It's a bit hacky, but I cannot find any better way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

1. Obtain the response object (in jsf - `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse()`, and cast to `HttpServletResponse`) or `the OutputStream` (JSF 2.0, the last method call above would be `getResponseOutputStream()`)
2. use the `write` methods on the response's `OutputStream`
3. set the proper `Content-Type` header

Comment: `print`? `write`! The `ExternalContext#getResponseOutputStream()` is btw JSF 2.0 only.

Comment: Where would I put this code? I have no JSF controllers or anything, just a bunch of webflow XML.

Comment: @mranders - well, you need some code at least - otherwise how are you obtaining the image in the first place?

Comment: I have some code in my service class, but it just maps the web service object to a bean. The data is in my bean object. Do you mean I should place the code in the bean object?

Comment: I don't know - a "bean" is a very wide term. And I can't see your application structure :)

Comment: The bean is a just a anemic model object. A data structure that the view uses to display stuff.

Comment: well, not there then. Somewhere in your web-related code. If there is no such - create a controller / managed bean.

Comment: But the data I want to serve is in the bean. Therein lies the problem.