# How can I render a file cached in a managed bean?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

Current versions: JSF 2.1, RichFaces 4.5.2

I got into the following problem:
I have an upload component in one of my web-pages which is going to upload images:

```
<h:graphicImage id="uploadedPict" value="__WHAT__?" alt="picture />

<rich:fileUpload id="imageStartUploadComponent"
                 fileUploadListener="#{MyBean.uploadStartImage}"
                 acceptedTypes="png,jpg"
                 immediateUpload="false">
    <a4j:ajax event="uploadcomplete" render="uploadedPict" />
</rich:fileUpload>
```

and the manged bean itself:

```
public class MyBean{

    private UploadedFile detailsImage;

    public void uploadStartImage(){
         //SETTING detailsImage here
    }

    //GET, SET, OTHER STUFF
}
```

I could invoke `UploadedFile::getData()` method to retrieve binary image data. But how can I render it into the web-page? `value` attribute is supposed to be assigned with an actual picture's URL. So it seems I'm going to have to write my own servlet...

**QUESTION:** Is there a way to avoid writing a servlet and render the picture right from managed bean's method returning its binary data?

UPDATE: I need to do this for showing uploaded picture's preview. Maybe there is another way to do that correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I serve binary content from a JSF/Webflow app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133982/how-can-i-serve-binary-content-from-a-jsf-webflow-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<a4j:mediaOutput>`:

```
<a4j:mediaOutput element="img" mimeType="image/jpeg" 
     createContent="#{bean.paint}" value="#{bean.file}">
</a4j:mediaOutput>
```

and the paint method:

```
public void paint(OutputStream stream, Object object) throws IOException {
    stream.write(((UploadedFile) object).getData());
    stream.close();
}
```

(check the [showcase example](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=fileUpload))